# C++ conversion of string to char * which is then returned

Tags: c++, string, char

i'm doing some work in c++ and came across this piece of code:

```
char* intToChar(RandomObject o) {
   string integerStr = to_string(o.toNumber());
   char * integerChar = new char[integerStr.size()+1];
   copy(integerStr.begin(), integerStr.end(), integerChar);
   integerChar[integerStr.size()] = '\0';
   return integerChar;
}
```

`integerChar` is returned and assigned like this:

```
struct Field {
   char *name;
   char *value;
};

std::vector<Field> rowData;

Field field;
field.name = i->key;
field.value = intToChar(i->value);
rowData.push_back(field);
```

but i don't see anywhere he would free `integerChar` or the `field` object ... is this bad? will this create a memory leak?

Comment: How does `o.toNumber()` compile with `o` being an `int` ?

Comment: oh damn, i just pulled those few lines from the code, it's in a much bigger function and o is something else. Good catch!

Comment: Ok :) And yes you should delete that somewhere if you don't wanna leak (yet an std::string or std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr would be better)

Comment: the problem is i don't know how :D unfortunately i didn't use c++/c for like 10 years and forgot most of it :/

Comment: @Paranaix How would a destructor help?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hm wait, I can write a delete statement in them? Oh, std::vector with automatic storage duration, how convenient...

Comment: @Paranaix What about copies of the struct? How will your destructor handle that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan rule of three - copies should be copied

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: probably yes. `intToChar` allocates memory, which is then assigned to `field.value`. If there is no `delete[]` called for `field.value` (directly or indireclty), the memory is leaked.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see the code uses both `string` (is it `std::string`) and `char*` which is bizarre to me. Stick with `string` and avoid dealing with memory allocation and release.

```
string intToChar(int o) 
{
   return to_string(o.toNumber());
}

struct Field {
   std::string name;
   std::string value;
};

Field field;
field.name = i->key;
field.value = intToChar(i->value);
rowData.push_back(field);
```

Comment: well, it's because of legacy reasons and old json parser :(

Comment: Well, stop using raw memory allocs all the same. Switch to `std::string`.

Comment: tried that, but it just breaks way more things than i have time to fix

Answer (score 0):

Every use of `new` must be matched with a use of `delete`. Or in this case, `delete[]`. So, yes, if the `delete[]` is missing, memory is leaked.

Comment: And how would you dete a struct with an address pointing to a char* which is inside a vector rowData ?

Comment: You delete an array using `delete[]`. Are you familiar with `new[]` and `delete[]`?

Comment: not very much, i just don't know how to delete a struct that is inside a std::vector

Comment: It doesn't matter where it is. You do it with `delete[]`. You shouldn't be using raw dynamic memory allocs. Switch to `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to free the `field` object (it was created on the stack in this case, so it will normally be discarded when the corresponding thread ends) but the memory for `integerChar`, allocated with `new`, has to be deallocated somewhere.

Comment: yes but how do you deallocate integerChar when it's returned? i would think that right before the return statement, but then you loose the contents of integerChar

Comment: Usually you deallocate the objects when you no longer need them. You do not need to do it in intToChar method itself, but you'd need to do it when either the `field` object goes out of scope (if it's the only owner of the integerChar object), or you assign some other value to it.